# Custom JSR 303 validation is not invoked

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

My custom JSR 303 validation is not getting invoked. Here is my code

my spring config has

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

My controller's handler method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="update", method = RequestMethod.POST , 
                consumes="application/json" , 
                produces="application/json"))
@ResponseBody
public  String update(@Valid @RequestBody MyBean myBean){
    return process(myBean);
}
```

MyBean (annotated with ValidMyBeanRequest):

```
@ValidMyBeanRequest
public class MyBean {

    private int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

ValidMyBeanRequest annotaion:

```
@Target({ TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = {MyBeanValidator.class})
public @interface ValidMyBeanRequest {
    String message() default "{validMyBeanRequest.message}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

MyBeanValidator class:

```
public class MyBeanValidator implements 
             ConstraintValidator<ValidMyBeanRequest, MyBean> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidMyBeanRequest constraintAnnotation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(MyBean myBean, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        boolean isValid = true;

        int id = myBean.getId();
        if(id == 0){
            isValid = false;
        }
        return isValid;
    }
}
```

My http POST request has below JSON data:

```
{id:100}
```

The problem is MyBeanValidator's isValid is not getting invoked.  I am using Spring 3.1.0 and HibernateValidator is in classpath.

Please see what I am missing??

**Update**: Updated handler method to include POST request type and consumes, produces values. Also included my http request with JSON data.

Comment: Does `@valid` work for standart constraints and normal (Form) command Objects (without `@RequestBody` )?

Comment: Also, is `myBean` binded correctly?

Comment: @n1ckolas myBean is bound correctly. I have json mapping; i would have got error if the field was not mapped correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you do get model correctly, in this case you are doing everything right, except one thing: you need to handle your validation's result manually.

For achieving this you need to add [BindingResult](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/BindingResult.html) object into list of your handler parameters, and then process validation constraints in the way you would like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="update")
@ResponseBody
public  String update(@Valid @ModelAttribute @RequestBody MyBean myBean, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()){
        return processErrors(myBean);
    }
    return process(myBean);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I do not want to bind the result and check if it has errors. I actually have a @ExceptionHandler annotated method in my controller to catch any validation exceptions. However I am getting an exception when I add BindingResult: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Errors/BindingResult argument declared without preceding model attribute`

Comment: This exception indicates, that you need to add `@ModelAttribute` for `MyBean` (already updated in the answer). For `ExceptionHandler`: you may try `@Validated` annotation, something like:  `String update(@Validated @RequestBody MyBean myBean) {...`

Comment: Hi n1ckolas, `@Validated` didn't help.  And if i add `@ModelAttribute` I am getting error. `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler parameter annotations are exclusive choices - do not specify more than one such annotation on the same parameter`. **But my problem is not handing validation errors. My validator is not getting invoked at all**. I have some debug statements in isValid which are not getting executed.

Comment: Second exception means, that you are trying to pass more then 2 `@ModelAttribute` in the same handler. And probably that's the cause of the issue, because I tried your input data locally and everything worked properly. So you probably need to add more information.

Comment: thanks for your time @n1ckolas. Please see the update on my post.

Comment: I don't have any other @ModelAttribute in my controller.

Comment: I added @Component annoation to the validator. but still it doesn't work.